# SpringBoot 2 JPA relationship between different schemas in postgres

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

Need help with this problem:
I have two tables in different schemas in the same db:

DB_test
 schema_1
 shema_2

in each schema i have different tables:

schema_1 -> client
schema_2 -> phone.

my code

table 1

```
@Entity @Table(schema = "schema_1") 
public class Client implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
private String name;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "client")
private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();
public PessoaFisica() {
   }
}
```

table 2

```
@Entity    
@Table(schema = "schema_2")
public class Phone implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
private String number;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_client")
private Client client;

public Client() {
   }
}
```

So the relationship does not work.
But if the two tables are in the same schema, it works.
What should I do for a schema table to see the table of another schema.

Comment: what is "So the relationship doesnt work"??? exception? table generation? what persistence code? etc etc

Comment: Because the tables are in different schemas, one does not "see" the other. If you were to write the sql, you had to define the schema: shcema_1.client schema_2.phone How do I do this in spingboot? Is there any annotation?

Comment: The whole point of specifying "schema" in `@Table` is so that a JPA provider can write the SQL using schema.table.col for you. So I repeat my question ... what happens

Comment: Im not close to pc right now, to see the error code. 
I'll update the information as soon as I get it.

Comment: But I think the mistake is this.
With pure sql, if I do not specify the schema, it can not make the relationship.
schema.table -> works
table -> does not work.

Well, he does not know in which schema the table I want to use.

I think the spring boot needs an annotation to fetch the schema in the table I want to make the relationship.
As in the annotation table, each one is in a different schema, I believe I have to pass some parameter in the attribute that makes the relationship, indicating the schema where the other table is.

Comment: i found the solution

     @JoinTable(schema = "schema_name" .....)

Comment: The "solution" to the problem that you still haven't defined the exception for. Great